# Maven not able to download dependencies using eclipse, proxy not working

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to build a maven project using eclipse. My overall problem is Maven will not connect to the online Maven repository to collect the necessary artifacts needed to build the project. I have tried using numerous proxies, but get the following errors:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{repo.maven.apache.org:443, proxy=HTTP @ /101.96.11.44:95 hostAddress=101.96.11.44 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0)
at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:210)
at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.makeTunnel(Connection.java:400)
at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:229)
at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:159)
at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:175)
at com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:120)
at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:330)
at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:319)
at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:241)
at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:271)
at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:228)
at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:199)
at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:79)
at io.takari.aether.okhttp.OkHttpAetherClient.execute(OkHttpAetherClient.java:154)
at io.takari.aether.okhttp.OkHttpAetherClient.get(OkHttpAetherClient.java:100)
at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.resumableGet(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:600)
at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:453)
at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.get(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:304)
... 48 more

Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: size=0 content=...
at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:200)
at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:190)
... 65 more
```

I have also tried connecting to another network that is not my own and have had no success.

When I do not use a proxy, I get the following errors:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:980)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1363)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1391)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:242)
at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:159)
at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:175)
at com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:120)
at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:330)
at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:319)
at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:241)
at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:271)
at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:228)
at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:199)
at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:79)
at io.takari.aether.okhttp.OkHttpAetherClient.execute(OkHttpAetherClient.java:154)
at io.takari.aether.okhttp.OkHttpAetherClient.get(OkHttpAetherClient.java:100)
at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.resumableGet(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:600)
at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:453)
at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.get(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:304)
... 48 more

Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:961)
... 67 more
```

The only solution that I have found is downloading the dependencies one by one from the Maven repository manually. Given that there are more than 100 dependencies left to install, I'd really prefer not to spend that much time getting this to work. If any other details need to be provided, I will be happy to do so.

Comment: You can try to manually verify with Curl if the proxy `101.96.11.44:95` works at all and if it requires an uncommon authentication.

Comment: What proxy is your browser using?

Comment: Thanks guys for the quick responses. eckes, would you be more specific on how to use curl on the proxy? David, I have tried using several different types of proxies, I couldn't name them all. None of them seem to be working, which makes me think that there's some kind of problem with my eclipse setup.

Answer (score 1):

Under Windows I resolved this problem by using `mvn install` in a command shell for my project.

Then I added/changed `<localRepository>` in the settings.xml of eclipse maven user settings to `c:/users/ttt/.m2/repository` where I found the downloaded dependencies.